# Checking for key and value in python dictionary

Tags: python

I need to check if key exists in Python dictionary and value of that is not null/empty for multiple keys before processing further.

```
exception = False

if 'key1' in d and d['key1']:
    pass
else:
    exception = True

if 'key2' in d and d['key2']:
    pass
else:
    exception = True

if 'key3' in d and d['key3']:
    pass
else:
    exception = True

if not exception:
    #Process it
```

I feel this code is very ugly and not Pythonic as well.

Can we write the logic better?

Comment: `if d.get('keyX'):`? You can also combine multiple checks with `any` or `all`.

Comment: Your `exception` variable is always true. Your ifs are all pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all` and a generator:

```
if all(k in d and d[k] for k in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']):
    pass
else:
    exception = True
```

You could actually skip using a flag:

```
if not all(k in d and d[k] for k in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']):
    # process
```

or

```
if any(k not in d or not d[k] for k in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']):
    # process
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `d.get(k)`:

```py
if all( d.get(k) for k in ["key1","key2","key3"]):
    exception = False
else:
    exception = True
```

or

```py
exception = all( d.get(k) for k in ["key1","key2","key3"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try/except` with `operator.itemgetter`, or use `dict.get`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
try:
    exception = not all(itemgetter('key1', 'key2', 'key3')(d))
except KeyError:
    exception = True
```

Or,

```
exception = not all(map(d.get, ('key1', 'key2', 'key3')))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the correct Bool.

```
exception = False
for k in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']:
    if k in d and d[k]:
        exception = True
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @mozway is more pythonic & better, but anyways here is another approach using a function.

```
def check_dict(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key not in ("key1", "key2", "key3"):
            return False
    return True
```